# Can't access variable in inner scope?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get this piece of SQL query to work. The problem is that I can't access `core_user.id` in the stuff in its parameters. I don't really know why.

```
SELECT
    core_user.id AS target, (
        SELECT
            COUNT(permission_id) AS permissions
        FROM (
            SELECT
                DISTINCT permission_id
            FROM (
                SELECT
                    id,
                    permission_id
                FROM
                    core_user_user_permissions
                WHERE
                    core_user_user_permissions.user_id = core_user.id
                UNION
                SELECT
                    id,
                    permission_id
                FROM
                    auth_group_permissions
                WHERE
                    auth_group_permissions.group_id IN (
                        SELECT
                            group_id
                        FROM
                            core_user_groups
                        WHERE
                            core_user_groups.user_id = core_user.id)) AS `permissions`) AS `derived`) AS `perms`
        FROM
            `core_user`
        WHERE
            `core_user`.`is_active` = TRUE
        GROUP BY
            `core_user`.`id`
        ORDER BY
            `perms` ASC
```

If i try `target.id` with `core_user AS target` it does not work either: `Unknown column 'target.id' in 'where clause'`

Expected Results:

```
+----------------------------------+-------+
| id                               | perms |
+----------------------------------+-------+
| ab7ec54bf9124dffb807fb89f9ea8036 |    0 |
| b54d4d3f97134dfcbc36ac193c0c1250 |    81 |
| c69ffa4d162b49129ff6a316da3caaa3 |    64 |
| f8ac73eee80044359c246f3b173aa631 |    0 |
+----------------------------------+-------+
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not easy to understand what one wants, if there is only an (invalid) query and no description of what it should retrieve. So this is just a best guess:

```
SELECT cu.id target,
       count(x.permission_id) perms
       FROM core_user cu
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT cuup.permission_id,
                              cuup.user_id
                              FROM core_user_user_permissions cuup
                              WHERE cuup.permission_id IS NOT NULL
                       UNION
                       SELECT agp.permission_id,
                              cug.user_id
                              FROM auth_group_permissions agp
                                   INNER JOIN core_user_groups cug
                                              ON cug.group_id = agp.group_id
                              WHERE agp.permission_id IS NOT NULL) x
                      ON x.user_id = cu.id
       WHERE cu.is_active = TRUE
       GROUP BY cu.id
       ORDER BY perms ASC;
```

Instead of getting the count in a subselect it left joins the permission IDs for each user. Grouping by the user ID than gets the (distinct, because the union already removed any duplicates and `id` is also unique in `core_user` (I assume)) count of the non null permission IDs of a user, which is what I believe you want.

(You may remove the `WHERE <alias>.permission_id IS NOT NULL` in the inner query, if there are not null constraints on the columns. The idea here is, that nulls aren't counted in the end anyway, so we want to discard them as early as possible.)

(Untested, as neither schema nor sample data was provided. May contain typos.)

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite it as:

```
SELECT core_user.id AS target,
   (SELECT COUNT(permission_id) AS permissions
    FROM (SELECT permission_id
          FROM core_user_user_permissions
          WHERE core_user_user_permissions.user_id = `core_user`.id
          UNION
          SELECT permission_id
          FROM auth_group_permissions
          WHEREauth_group_permissions.group_id IN (
                        SELECT group_id
                        FROM core_user_groups
                        WHERE core_user_groups.user_id = `core_user`.id)
          ) AS `derived`
  ) AS `perms`
FROM `core_user`
WHERE  `core_user`.`is_active` = TRUE
GROUP BY `core_user`.`id`
ORDER BY `perms`;
```

I've removed one level of nested subquery in SELECT list.

Comment: I still get `Unknown column 'core_user.id' in 'where clause'`. I also need to use `DISTINCT`.

Comment: @P.Nick https://dbfiddle.uk Table structures + Sample data. Plus you don't need `DISTINCT` because `UNION` removes duplicates.

Comment: I did not quite understand how it works so I posted it here: https://pastebin.com/naMJ8Ryi

Comment: @P.Nick What I meant was scripts to recreate your case such as CREATE TABLE ... and INSERT INTO .... You simply choose `MySQL` copy and paste and share link here.

Answer (score 0):

Well I hope I could get your expected result by excluding group premissons:

```
SELECT core_user.id AS target, 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(permission_id)) AS permissions
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT cuup.id as id, cuup.permission_id as permission_id
            FROM core_user_user_permissions cuup
            -- WHERE cuup.user_id = cu.id  
            --VV-- this should be a join
            JOIN core_user cu ON cu.id = cuup.user_id
        )
    ) AS `perms`
FROM `core_user`
WHERE `core_user`.`is_active` = TRUE
GROUP BY `core_user`.`id`
ORDER BY `perms` ASC
```

Comment: It does not work quite as expected, see here for more info: https://pastebin.com/qbS8Vj2t

Comment: Nope, still not.

Comment: That's weird, lemme check.

Comment: @P.Nick Can you provide me results from `select id from core_user`, `select user_id from core_user_groups` and `select user_id from core_user_user_permissions` ?

Comment: Try again, I have changed the sql, by guessing what you mean by expected results.